# with Python, how can I save a json dumps as a CouchDB document?

Tags: python, json, couchdb, couchdb-python

Given the following example data :

```
[
    "this",
    1000,
    {
        "that": 1
    }
]
```

(which is valid json according to jsonlint.com)

```
data=json.loads('["this",1000,{"that":1}]')
```

when I try to save that structure to CouchDB, it generates an error.

```
db['testdoc']=json.dumps(data)
ServerError: (400, ('bad_request', 'Document must be a JSON object'))
```

How then, should I save that type of structure?

I'm clearly missing something important.

Comment: You are passing a string, couchdb-python does the conversion to JSON for you. All you need to do is make sure your python object is serializable.

Comment: I see, so a string is not serializable?
I notice I can use 

`db['testdoc']={'data':data}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this site: https://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Getting_started_with_Python, simply write:

```
data = json.loads('["this",1000,{"that":1}]')
db['testdoc'] = data
```

Here, `data` is a classic Python list.